# Is it possible to track emails to the extent that we get counts for "READ","DELETED","SOFT BOUNCE","HARD BOUNCE"?

Tags: email, email-validation

The title being self explanatory, i would like to add some points to it.

1.Firstly, is it possible to track all these (READ,DELETED,SOFT BOUNCE,HARD BOUNCE) without  using  third party API?
2. If no, which third party services provide you the same ?

I am aware about the `<img src="send-identifiers-to-this-url-to-track"/>`, but this can only get me "No.of Reads/Forwards", but not deleted.

Anybody in for help ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can detect with your own software and no third party, though I don't know how they map onto the categories you list:

1. Tracking images and links, like you said (READ).
2. No mail server to take the message, e.g There might not be any MX record for the domain or your mailserver IP might be blocked by DNSBL (maybe what you mean by HARD BOUNCE?)
3. [Mail server response codes](http://www.aspiresoft.com/email-server-status-codes/).  This might tell you for example:

   1. Your email was rejected because the mailbox was over capacity etc (probably SOFT BOUNCE)
   2. Rejected because it's spam (probably HARD BOUNCE)
   3. Greylisted or something (probably SOFT BOUNCE)

There is basically nothing you can to detect the difference between unread and deleted messages though.  That is also true of third party services. You will not even detect read messages unless your recipient turns on tracking images or clicks on a tracking link.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to get this information, for instance I had to implement a [postfix log analyzer](https://github.com/FgForrest/Postfix-Deliverability-Analytics) that is mining the bounce information (soft/hard) and the reason why they occured and make it available via API in a structured form.